# create folder in Internal Memory

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to create a folder, but I am unable to get the methods for creating folder in Internal Memory(phone)

[image: like this picture]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJgVd.jpg

and how to know all the names of my files in my folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1. Create folder in internal memory

Make sure you have enabled WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Option 1

```
val directoryName = File("/sdcard/YourFolderName/") 
directoryName .mkdirs()
```

Option 2

```
val directoryName = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourFolderName") 
directoryName .mkdirs()
```

Problem 2. Know all the names of my files in my folder

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);
        if (directory.exists()) {
            String[] children = directory.list();
            if (children != null) {
                for (String child : children) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "filename: "+child);

                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Directory does not exist");
        }
```